# How to expand layer group by code OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

My question is simple: I need expand a layer group, just like the event clic in the "+" button but programmatically.

I have a group in this image

[image: Group]

I need expand the group like this

[image: Group expanded]

How can I do this programmatically in Openlayers3.
Ty for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this
for each group

```js
var Group1 = new ol.layer.Group({
  title: 'Group1',
  openInLayerSwitcher: false,
  visible: false,
  layers:[
    new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'SubGroup1',
     openInLayerSwitcher: false,
     visible: false,
     layers: Object.values(G1)
    }),
    new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'SubGroup2',
     openInLayerSwitcher: false,
     visible: false,
     layers: Object.values(G2)
    })]
        });
        G1['Layer1'] = new ol.layer.Tile({
      title: "Layer1 in Group 1",
      baseLayer: false,
      visible: false,
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
       wrapX: false,
       url: '/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'//depends on the layer type
      })
     });
```

And so on..

Answer (score 0):

On Openlayers site, under examples section you have one fine example how can one implement similar behavior.

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-group.html

Also, something similar is explained [here](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter02_03_layer_groups.html), but keep in mind that this example uses 3.4.0 version.